# В БД не добавляются русские символы.

Tags: кодировка, ajax, php

Здравствуйте. Поялвилась такая проблема. Есть добавление новостей с помощью AJAX. В ней есть проверка при добавлении на наличие символов. Если пользователь пытается отправить пустой запрос то выводит ошибку. Так вот, при добавлении записи латинскими буквами все нормально добавляестя. А если русскими символами то добавляется пустая новость. Как это понимать? Думаю во всем виновата кодировка, но у меня сайт на utf-8, БД MySql тоже на utf-8. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Само поле в таблице имеет кодировку "utf8-general-ci"?

Можно на код ajax и php посмотреть, если не сложно? И структуру таблицы..

Comment: Да, само поле также имеет такую кодировку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Господин [@Luntegg](/users/7345/luntegg), не вводите людей в заблуждение. utf8-general-ci это никакая не кодировка.

[@Николай Никонов](/users/5725/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), исходники приложения должны быть сохранены в кодировке utf-8. Вы говорите, что так и есть. Посмотрите в файл my.ini и в директиве [mysqld] укажите кодировку utf-8. Как это сделать написано например [здесь](http://dedic.ru/node/213)